# What is the difference between setpgrp and tcsetpgrp

Tags: c, linux, unix, libc, tty

```
int tcsetpgrp(int fildes, pid_t pgid_id);
```

and

```
int setpgrp(void);
```

I don't really understand difference and purpose of this two functions. Of course `man page` has been previously read.

But I still don't understand purpose and use of this functions. It is clear to set group. But why do we need both of them. What is the difference between terminal group and process group.
Please explain this. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tcsetprgrp` is a function that is used for set the process group based on the file descriptor which is connected to terminal.  If the file descriptor not connected to the terminal that time it will give the error.

`setpgrp` is used for making the calling process as a process group leader. Refer this [link.](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/tsetpgp.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`tcsetpgrp` is used to set the foreground process group of a controlling terminal (for job control functions).

`setpgrp` is used to add some process to a group.